# Set default registers per line in register window in Ride7 IDE

Tags: debugging, assembly, ide, cpu-registers

This question is about the CPU registers view in the Ride7 IDE by Raisonance.

When debugging, the default amount of registers displayed per line is 8, but I prefer this window to be long and thin, and end up changing this to 1 register per line for each debugging run. This is annoying, and I was wondering if there was a way to change the default?

I've looked in all the obvious places, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the Raisonance guys, and this is the answer I got:

> Hi Øystein (I got to find out this one
>   on my keyboard!)
>
> Sorry, but we do not have this
>   capability yet. The registers window
>   is hardcoded so it would not be too
>   easy to modify it.
>
> I hope this helps, Bruno Richard, PhD.
>   RAISONANCE - 17, avenue Jean Kuntzmann
>   - F-38330 Montbonnot St Martin - FRANCE

So there are no easy ways (hex-editing the executable, anyone?)